# React router props url

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm new to react so please forgive my terminology...

I am trying to create a view on a website for portfolio items, each portfolio item will use the same view but have a unique url...

site.com/project1, site.com/project2, i want these to be created from json data, how would I go about creating these on the fly rather than hard coding these? example I add project3 (with properties) to json file, this page will be added to list?

If it makes any difference I am not using redux, just simple SPA...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the best way in your case is to define routes like this

```
<Router>
  ...
  <Route path="/project/:id" component={Project}>
</Router>`
```

So you can you use id later in your component to load certain project

```
class Project extends Component {
  ...
  componentDidMount() {
    loadProject(this.props.params.id);
  }
  ...
}
```